# Difference between buffered reader and file reader and scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

Can anyone explain me the difference between the class `BufferedReader`, `FileReader` and `Scanner`? and which one to use when I want to read a text file?

Comment: If you have to read a file you can use apache commons io: `String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);` so that you donot have to worry about readers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well:

- `FileReader` is just a `Reader` which reads a file, using the platform-default encoding (urgh)
- `BufferedReader` is a wrapper around another `Reader`, adding buffering and the ability to read a line at a time
- `Scanner` reads from a variety of different sources, but is typically used for interactive input. Personally I find the API of `Scanner` to be pretty painful and obscure.

To read a text file, I would suggest using a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` (so you can specify the encoding) and then wrapped in a `BufferedReader` for buffering and the ability to read a line at a time.

Alternatively, you could use a third-party library which makes it simpler, such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Or if you're using Java 7, it's already available for you in `java.nio.file.Files`:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("foo.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Java 7 has the same thing: `Files.readAllLines`.

Comment: @dbw As opposed to... Guava's `readLines`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks, hadn't seen that. Will add it into the answer.

Comment: Is it `readLines` have facility to fetch desired number of rows or just stop after `n` lines, I think it will also load all the lines to memory so it will be problem for big files....

Comment: @dbw: If you only want to process some lines, there are alternatives in Guava such as the `CharStreams.readLines(InputSupplier, LineProcessor)` method.

Comment: great anwer but will you explain me thus "Personally I find the API of Scanner to be pretty painful and obscure." I mean why?

Comment: @piechuckerr: The fact that there are so many questions with it being used badly is pretty damning. It defies the expectations of users in many cases. My experience is that it's hard to use robustly and correctly.

Answer (score 3):

And as per your question for reading a text file you should use `BufferedReader` because `Scanner` hides **IOException** while `BufferedReader` **throws** it immediately.

`BufferedReader` is **synchronized** and `Scanner` is not.

`Scanner` is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream.

`BufferedReader` just reads the stream.

For more info follow the link (http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2009/2/Difference-Scanner-Method-Buffered.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see a reason why read operation needs to be synchronized. Do you understand the reasoning behind this design decision ?