# Java File Reading Issues

Tags: java, file, execution

I am having some very wierd issues while attempting to read a file.

Its only a few lines of simple code, but for some reason its thinking that my file has 8 lines of wierd rumbo jumbo text, while it has 2 lines and 4 letters in each line.

Code (Executed once, it's reading the correct file)

```
Scanner scanner = null;

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/level.txt"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    Main.main.log(lines.size() + " size");
```

File (level.txt, with no spaces)

```
sssas
sssas
```

Output:

```
8 Size
```

Its super weird since it's only a few lines and a simple file.

Any help, suggestions or error's made? There are no stacktraces!

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: I don't think your file contains what you say it contains.

Comment: Print `lines` and see what's in the list.

Comment: It does, but if your not convinced copy my code into your IDE and test it your self.

Comment: [Here you go.](https://ideone.com/lvJjWP) Prints 2 as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue to consider is as @Sotirios Delimanolis says, you may read from a wrong txt file.

The second issue is that if you are perfectly sure about reading from the correct .txt file, the solution is to read with reading scanner.hasNextLine() while appending to the "lines" variable.

I think the problem occurs when you read with "hasNext()" which reads token by token, and go into next step with "scanner.nextLine()" which goes to the next line.

For example you may use the following;

```
Scanner scanner = null;

ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/level.txt"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { /* difference is here */
    lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

Main.main.log(lines.size() + " size");
```

***EDIT:***

You can use the following code and modify it however you want.
I think the problem is also occurs when you are reading the File. To read the file you can use new File() constructor instead of your choice. See below:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("level.txt")); /* difference is here */
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { /* difference is here */
    lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

System.out.println(lines.size()); // gives output 2.
```

Comment: The output is the exact same as before, could you try it in your own IDE?

Comment: I tried and give a correct solution. Please see the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Hm, mine is not working. The file is being read though, because it gets an error if its not there. Would an .rtf work as exspected?

Comment: Do not use / tag when sending the file name. May be this causes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 one-liner to read a file to a list:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(
    Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/level.txt").toURI()),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
```

Comment: @Chris You just made it a four-liner!!1

Comment: Sorry :) ... "a one-expressioner"?

Comment: This works, but returns some wonky string. How can I make it so it returns purely the file (in the list of course)

Comment: Can you elabarote on wonky string? With this code you have all lines of the file in the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go on different kind of method which is more correct to do..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This will do the trick perfectly.. hope that helps

EDIT:

If you would like to read file from classpath of the project you can use the following:

```
 InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Somethink like that will be fine.. I am not saying you cannot do it with scanner.. IMHO I think this is better.. But it is a matter of choice and not big architecture problem.. Consideration is yours :)

Comment: Basically Scanner is more appropriate to use with input from user... and its api is not the best.. for reading files it is more appropriate to use BufferReader.. Look at this link for example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838244/difference-between-buffered-reader-and-file-reader-and-scanner-class

Comment: Easier to use doesn't mean the other solution is wrong. Also, you're reading from the file system, while OP is reading from the classpath. Fix those two things and you should be fine.

Comment: Scanner is used if you want to parse the input, or getting input from the cmd.. BufferReader is just reading plain text which this is the situation here..Don't you agree?

Comment: How can I read from where the file is located in my src, and not from anywhere on my computer?

Comment: Yeah, how do I read from the class path with this example above?

Comment: You can use a `Scanner` to read from any `InputStream` just fine.

Comment: InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()                         .getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

Somethink like that will be fine..
I am not saying you cannot do it with scanner.. IMHO I think this is better.. But it is a matter of choice and not big architecture problem.. Consideration is yours :)

Comment: I want you to edit your answer. Rephrase it and add the details in your previous comment.

Comment: Added it to my answer